# Miniatura do post no Wordpress não aparece no Facebook

Tags: wordpress, post, blog

**Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema:**

Estou criando um site em Wordpress e quero que quando eu for publicar as postagens dele no Facebook apareça aquela miniatura da imagem do post, porem no lugar dela está aparecendo a logo do site. Não sei como resolver isso, por isso peço a ajuda de vocês.

Peço por favor que usem explicações simples, pois não domino muito nesse assunto.

**Abaixo está o erro que está dando lá no depurador do Facebook:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode ser apenas uma falta de Open Graph tags... uma forma mais amigável de resolver isso seria com algum plugin como o [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/), como o objetivo dele é tornar seu conteúdo mais amigável pros mecanismos de pesquisa e tudo o mais, ele se encarrega de acrescentar tais Open Graph tags.

Comment: Value amigo, muito obrigado.